# Chrome iPhone simulator does not match iOS native environment display

Tags: html, ios, css, google-chrome, debugging

I've built a small basic portfolio page based on a bootstrap template. The top features a blue header with an animated gif I built on top of that with a parallax effect. The animation displays and runs properly on everything EXCEPT for iPhones. Even the Chrome simulator mode for iPhones displays properly. Non iPhones also display it correctly.

I'm definitely a newbie when it comes to front end, and can't figure out how to debug this, since it shows up fine on the Chrome simulator tool where I normally  do my debugging.

Any help would be much appreciated.

[View my site here--](http://www.heytherepete.com)

Comment: Can you clarify whether this question is looking for answers on *how* to debug it yourself, like in St. G's answer, or whether you're looking for others to help you debug? That you link to your site at the bottom makes it look like you're asking for the latter. If it is the latter, then you need to include enough code to duplicate your issue in your question.

Answer (score 1):

The Chrome device emulator will help you do most of the work, but it's not an iOS simulator. You can use the iOS simulator in XCode paired with OS X Safari's developer tools (inspect iOS Simulator) if you really want to debug for iOS.